# How does Facebook Javascript SDK determine whether to present a touch or WAP login dialog?

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

When using the pop-up OAuth dialog, you can decide whether to present a WAP dialog or a touch dialog but when using the Javascript client-side, when the display type is not specified, how does Facebook decide whether to show a WAP dialog or a touch dialog?

Since it seems like in July 2012, the WAP dialog will be deprecated, will it also no longer be presented by the Javascript SDK?